# Find edited textbox value inside DataItemTemplate on Button click event

Tags: devexpress, aspxgridview

I want to get the edited value in the textbox on a button click event. I have tried this code

```
string Value = gvSample.GetRowValues(i, "Word").ToString();
```

but it gives me the old value of the textbox.

I also tried

```
TextBox txtTrans = (TextBox)gvSample.FindControl("txtSample");
```

`string Value = txtTrans.Text;`

but txtTrans always returns NULL.

Please help.

Comment: do you need to get it on the server or on a client? In what event are you using your code (Init, Load, etc.)?

Comment: Check this [ASPxGridView - How to find a control in DataRow](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q356518)

Comment: I need to find the textbox on Button Click event (Code Behind)

Comment: @NiranjanKala: I have already gone through the sample you sent. Didn't help.